# $f^{*}\omega = \det(df)dx_{1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{n}$ for $f(x_{1},...,x_{n}) = (y_{1},...,y_{n})$ and $\omega = dy_{1}\wedge \cdots dy_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a differentiable map, given by
>   $$f(x_{1},...,x_{n}) = (y_{1},...,y_{n}),$$
>   and $\omega = dy_{1}\wedge \cdots dy_{n}$. Show that
>   $$f^{*}\omega = \det(df)dx_{1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{n}.$$

**My attempt.**

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
f^{*}\omega & = & f^{*}(dy_{1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dy_{n})\\
            & = & f^{*}(dy_{1})\wedge \cdots \wedge f^{*}(dy_{n})\\
            & = & d(f^{*}y_{1}) \wedge \cdots \wedge d(f^{*}dy_{n})\\
            & = & d(y_{1}\circ f)\wedge \cdots \wedge d(y_{n}\circ f)\\
            & = & df_{1}\wedge \cdots \wedge df_{n}\\
            & = & \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{j}}dx_{j}\wedge \cdots \wedge \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f_{n}}{\partial x_{j}}dx_{j},
\end{eqnarray*}$$

but, $dx_{i} \wedge dx_{i} = 0$. So,
$$\frac{n!}{n!(n-n!)} = 1$$
is the number of distinct combinations of $dx_{i}$. Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $n$ elements, then

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
f^{*}\omega & = & \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{j}}dx_{j}\wedge \cdots \wedge \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f_{n}}{\partial x_{j}}dx_{j}\\
            & = & \sum \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{\sigma(1)}}\cdots \frac{\partial f_{n}}{\partial x_{\sigma(n)}}dx_{\sigma(1)} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{\sigma(n)}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Now, I know that changing $dx_{\sigma(1)} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{\sigma(n)}$ with $dx_{1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{n}$ should be appear $\mathrm{sign}(\sigma)$ in the sum, but I cannot justify. Probably it is trivial, but can someone help me? I know that this question was asked here, but I didn't find this detail.

Comment: I think you're already there; as you say, when you have $dx_{\sigma(1)} \vee \cdots \vee dx_{\sigma(n)}$, this is equal to $\text{sgn}(\sigma)dx_1 \vee \cdots \vee dx_n$. The reason for this is just the property that if $\alpha, \beta$ are $k$, $\ell$ forms (respectively), then $\alpha \vee \beta = (-1)^{k\ell}\beta\vee\alpha$. Using this and the associativity of the wedge product should get what you want.

Comment: @Chris, yes! I couldn't justify why $(-1)^{k\ell}$ is $\mathrm{sign}(\sigma)$. But I was just confusing myself in the definition of $\det$. Thank you!